# Window Sizing on High DPI Screen?

Tags: playonlinux, dpi, hdpi

I have a 4K monitor set up for 2x scaling using the GNOME tweak tool. When I open PlayOnLinux the menus are nearly untraversable and when I go through the menus to install a game, the next and exit buttons aren't even visible which makes it impossible to install anything with the software.

Is there a way I can force the scaling to normal and handle it small or correct this issue? Below are some screen shots of what's happening.

[image] 
Initial Start Screen + Search Menu

[image]
Installation Menu With Missing Next/Quit Buttons

Let me know if you need any more information and thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: On KDE, after changing window scaling, I experience the same issue.

Comment: Here's the link for Bug #5543 on PlayOnLinux:
https://www.playonlinux.com/en/issue-5543.html

Answer (score 0):

Change your system configuration for the installation to non hi-def and change it back afterwards.

```
system settings --> general --> desktop scaling
```

You only need to do this during the installation of new software (not for starting and configurating existing ones) and you can keep the settings windows open, so it's not as big a pain as it seems at first. I still suggest to open an issue on their [official forum](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/forum-74-General_discussion.html)